# SIGSEGV on C++/Glade/gtkmm

Tags: c++, glade, gtkmm, segmentation-fault

I'm creating my first GUI application with C++ using gtkmm and Glade.
I had to merge various tutorials, because none I found is supporting Glade in combination with Gtk::Application and various classes.
See the code below:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc,argv,"org.gtkmm.ex");  
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
    builder->add_from_file("gui02.glade");

    HelloWorld* helloworld;
    std::cout << "helloworld compl." << std::endl;

    app->run(*helloworld);


    return 0;
}
```

helloworld.hpp

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{
protected:
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;

    Gtk::Button *btn1;
    Gtk::Label *lb1;

public:
    HelloWorld(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade);

protected:
    void on_button1_clicked();
};
```

helloworld.cpp

```
#include "helloworld.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace Gtk;

HelloWorld::HelloWorld(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade) : 
    Gtk::Window(cobject), builder(refGlade)
{
    builder->get_widget("label1", lb1);
    builder->get_widget("button1", btn1);

    btn1->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &HelloWorld::on_button1_clicked));
}

void HelloWorld::on_button1_clicked()
{
    lb1->set_text("HW!");
}
```

Compiling using:

```
g++ main.cpp helloworld.cpp -o main `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Result in the command line:

> Start
>
> helloworld compl.
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Debugging with gdb (relevant extract, you get the full output if neccessary)

> Glib::RefPtr::operator-> (this=0x7fffffffdd10) at /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/refptr.h:260
>   260   return pCppObject_;
>
> Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00007ffff7a4799e in Gtk::Widget::signal_hide() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1

Because I'm quite new to C++ (having some experience with C#), I'm not so used to pointers. Where is the error in this case?

Using a different code, where I create a Window* and use "app->run(*window)" works pretty fine, so the error occurs somewhere in the new app->run() and the outsourcing in class "HelloWorld".

Comment: The official gtkmm documentation does have an example that uses Glade and Gtk::Application: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-accessing-widgets.html.en and this one uses derived-widgets, as you seem to want: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes here `app->run(*helloworld);`
You try to dereference an empty pointer. That pointer does not point to an object in memory.
Do it like this:

```
HelloWorld* helloworld = new HelloWorld();
std::cout << "helloworld compl." << std::endl;
app->run(*helloworld);
```

Comment: Interesting thought, but it results in the following error:
`main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:`
`main.cpp:44:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘HelloWorld::HelloWorld()’
  HelloWorld* helloworld = new HelloWorld();
                                          ^
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
`
Because the candidates expect arguments.

Comment: If you want to instantiate the HelloWorld from the glade file, you need to call get_widget_derived(), as in the official example: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en